# android.process.acore has stopped and :app:installdebug FAILED

Tags: android-studio, react-native, react-android

I was running my react Native application successfully till yesterday. Today, when I tried to start my pixel AP! 23 phone emulator, I got the below error saying "unfortunately the process android.process.acore has stopped". Below is the screen shot. After seeing this error, I tried to Factory reset the phone, but still this error persists. I also tried to clear cache and clear data from phone settings.

[image: error]

I pressed Ok for this error message and tried to run my application using the command

react-native run-android

when I did this I got the below error message saying:

:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.826 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:

below is the screen shot:

[image]

the application was running fine till yesterday. I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the older version of android studio and downloaded the new one. I also Created a new Virtual device for Pixel phone and everything started working.